# Does walking on crops hurt them?

Tags: stardew-valley

Does walking on crops damage them in Stardew Valley? Will I lose seeds or grow lower quality produce?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to a forum post on Steam by players (http://steamcommunity.com/app/413150/discussions/0/405692758710999007/) they have not encountered any instance of crop damage due to waking on them.

Comment: I wanted to mention that it appears that walking over crops impedes on your movement speed, but does not appear to damage them in any way.